# C++ code not finding file

Tags: c++, list, ifstream

I'm trying to create a program that will concatenate (add two lists of integers together) 
each list is stored as a text file. I want the C++ program to open list1.txt and list2.txt

I can't actually get it to work though. I've put two lists of integers names list1 and list2 respectively however I'm getting the output cannot find list1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ifstream findlist1("list1.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
   if(!findlist1)
   {
      cout << "Cannot find list 1.\n";
      return 1;
   }
   ifstream findlist2("list2.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
   if(!findlist2)
   {
      cout << "Cannot find list 2.\n";
      return 1;
   }
   ofstream out("list3out.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);

   if(!out)
   {
      cout << "Unable to output file ";
      return 1;
   }

   out << in1.rdbuf();
   out << " " << flush;
   out << in2.rdbuf();

   return 0;
}
```

EDIT = SOLUTION:

My files were called test1.txt and were therefore showing up to the program as test1.txt.txt

Comment: If this is homework you should tag it as such and describe the kinds of things you've tried already.

Comment: You need to match your file extensions - if your code uses `.txt` extensions, then your file must have them also.

Comment: Sure thing, thanks for the tip! the text files have the appropriate .txt extensions and still doesn't work.

Comment: Are the input files in the same folder/directory as where you are running the program?

Comment: I bet that a full path would work.  You're making an assumption regarding your application's running directory that is incorrect.

Comment: If this is visual studio I believe the default working directory when you debug is the folder containing the project file.

Comment: Are those files open in an editor that might be preventing them from being opened elsewhere?  As a personal aside, I've never used or trusted the bool operator on file streams.  I always test `if(!findlist1.good())`.

Comment: If you solved this, it would be a good idea to answer your own question and then accept it (it helps indicate the question is answered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine, you may try using absolute path or put the files in the same directory of executable

Comment: So the files have always been in the same directory, I used the full path and still no avail. Full path being C:\user\admin\desktop\code\

Comment: @TimothyFord Full path to the code?  Or the project?  Or the executable?

Comment: @TimothyFord: If you’re using backslashes as path separators, be sure to escape them as double-backslashes, or use `/` instead.

Comment: @JonPurdy: Did you mean escape them as `\\\`?  And yeah, that's what I suspect as well. EDIT: Ok, I see why you had a problem with that :D

Comment: made appropriate changes still no luck!

Comment: @TimothyFord, Your full path isn't. You need something like `C:\user\admin\desktop\code\list1.txt`, keeping the escaped backslashes in mind. Mind you that if this is Windows 7, that should be `Users`, not `user`.

Comment: @TimothyFord It surely works well on my side - can you show your code when use absolute path? and when you are using relative path, when are you starting the executable? (the current working directory)

Comment: So I'm using the visual studio command prompt to compile it, in Windows 7. I have the absolute file, previous ones were just examples

`code    ifstream in1("C:/users/Timothy/Desktop/assignment/list1.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
   if(!in1)
   {
      cout << "Cannot find list 1.\n";
      return 1;
   }`.

Comment: I've checked to see if it's case sensitive, apparently not. It compiles fine, it's in the same directory. I'm so perplexed right now.

Comment: @TimothyFord weird... can you open list1.txt using a notepad or something? is that file really exist?

Comment: So here is a screen shot of the file it's stored in. [link](http://imgur.com/cbvuU)

Comment: anyone got any more tips? I need this in for tomorrow. I'm having a mental breakdown. Is there  another way to do the same thing?!?!

Comment: try fopen if you can open the file, here is an example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/, remember us "r", not "w" to open an existing file

Comment: @TimothyFord woo... I should have noticed this in your screenshot:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, all relative paths are relative to the project's [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). The default seems to be the project directory - meaning that if in `C:\SolutionX\ProjectY\Build\ProjectY.exe` you try to open the path "file.txt", Windows will look for `C:\SolutionX\ProjectY\file.txt`. If you'd like to change this directory, the setting is in the project's Configuration Properties under Debugging as "Working Directory".

Note that if you double click the executable manually rather than running it through Visual Studio, its working directory will be its current location. If instead you run the program from a command line, the working directory will be your working directory in the command line.

Comment: If I click the executable the program still does not create the 3rd text file. I'm running it through the visual studio 2010 command prompt